# Why does after i did 'checkout master', changes i did in the new branch show up in master?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I am a beginner to git:

I created new branch and when I did `git checkout master`, the files still exist in the IDE (I used Webstorm).
When I am in the new branch, I created a new file and did commit it before checkout. I don't think this is suppose to happen. What is supposed to happen is that the changes I did in the new branch should not show up in `master` or the files should disappear in Webstorm after I checkout `master`

Why does this happen?

Commands I did:

```sh
git checkout articles
git add trial.html
git commit -m 'new articles' 
git checkout master
```

Comment: @chepner No, if a file is tracked in one branch and not in another it should be deleted when checking out that "another" branch.

Comment: Can you show the output of `git status` after switching to master? And by "commands I did", these where the **exact** commands you did? Or did you, for instance, add the file, then change it, did not add the latest changes, did a commit?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Huh; is that a newer behavior or configurable? I could have sworn I remembered such files remaining in the working directory at some point.

Comment: If you *ignore* a file using .gitignore on one branch, and don't ignore it on another, it will look as if changes to files appear in some branches but not all, but if you delete a file on branch A, then check out branch B and the file reappear, if you then checkout branch A again, the file will disappear. Whether it was there before, or never was doesn't matter, it's whether it is currently being tracked on the branch that controls this.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of "articles" is your branch you want to commit to and "master" is your branch you want to see the coming commit from the "articles" branch:

```
git checkout articles
git add trial.html
git commit -m 'new articles'
git push
git checkout master
git merge origin/articles
```

Answer (score 0):

> Commands I [ran]:
>
> ```
> git checkout articles
> git add trial.html
> git commit -m 'new articles'
> ```

None of these commands *created a new file*, so there's something missing from your question.

Note that Git itself is not an IDE.  IDEs vary in quality and abilities, and some IDEs may not notice changes that have taken place in your working tree.

To understand how Git works here, remember that Git is all about *commits*.  The repository itself primarily consists of commits.  While commits *contain* files, they are not files themselves.  The repository does not hold *files* directly.  What this means is that any files you see in your *working tree* (or in your IDE) are *not in Git*.  At most, they were *copied out of Git*—i.e., out of a commit—earlier.

You can also use these files as part of the process of making *new* commits.  In other version control systems (VCSes), this is quite straightforward, as these VCSes make the new commits from these files.  This is not the case for Git, however.  To *really* understand this, it's necessary to back up a bit and examine commits more closely.

#### Commits are numbered

Every commit that can or does exist in a Git repository has a unique number.  These numbers are not simple counting numbers: Git does not start with commit #1, and then go on to commits 2, 3, and so on.  Instead, each commit gets a unique but random-looking *hash ID*.  This hash ID is used for *this* commit only, in *every Git repository in the universe.*<sup>1</sup>  This means that if some other Git repository comes along and hands your Git a hash ID, your Git can check to see if it already has this, just by looking at the number.  If your Git *doesn't* have this, your Git can get it from the other Git.  If your Git *does* have the number already, it already has the entire commit, and needs nothing from the other Git.

The *way* Git achieves this numbering is to use a cryptographic hash function (currently SHA-1, with SHA-256 coming).  Git runs this function over the bytes that make up the internal commit object.  This means that *nothing inside a commit can ever change*.<sup>2</sup>  All commits are frozen for all time.

---

<sup>1</sup>The [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) tells us that this numbering system *must* fail eventually.  The numbers are large enough to, we hope, make the first failure happen after the universe ends.  This requires very large hash IDs.  This particular constraint is further relaxed by allowing two Git repositories that never meet to re-use hash IDs.  I call these [doppelgängers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelg%C3%A4nger), complete with the traditional connotation of bad luck: it's best to avoid them, in case the two Git repositories accidentally *do* meet.

<sup>2</sup>In fact, nothing in any internal Git object can ever change.  Git checks that the hash ID, which Git uses as the key in a simple [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), matches the hash of the data once the data have been retrieved using that key.  If the stored data do not hash correctly, Git assumes that the underlying data have been damaged, e.g., by disk error.  Magnetic media drives generally have an expected undetected error rate of about 1 in 10<sup>17</sup> or worse, but Git will detect virtually all of these errors.

---

#### Commits have two parts

Each commit stores two things:

- A commit holds a full snapshot of every file that Git knew about, in the form it had at the time you (or whoever) made the commit.
- Along with the snapshot, a commit holds some *metadata*.  The metadata gives information about the commit itself, such as who made it (name and email address) and when.  The metadata include a log message, which you get to supply; but they also include data that Git supplies on its own.

A crucial part of the metadata is that each commit contains the raw commit hash ID of some set of *earlier* commits.  Most commits contain exactly one hash ID: these commits are *ordinary* commits.  Commits with *no* earlier-commit hash ID are called *root commits*, and I suspect most repositories have just one such commit (though it's possible to create more).  Commits with *two or more* earlier-commit hash IDs are called *merge commits*.  We'll ignore all but ordinary commits here.

The trick that Git performs with this earlier-commit-hash-ID is to form commits into simple backwards-looking chains.  Let's draw such a chain right now.  Instead of the actual hash IDs, let's use single uppercase letters to stand in for the hash IDs.  Let's further assume that the *last* commit in this chain has hash ID `H`, and draw the chain like this, with the last commit on the right:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

We know that commit `H` holds a full snapshot of every file, in some read-only frozen-for-all-time form.  So does earlier commit `G`.  Commit `H` holds the hash ID *of* commit `G`, so we say that `H` *points to* `G`.

This all means that if we give Git the hash ID of commit `H`, Git can find the commit in its database, read it out, find all of its files, *and* find the hash ID of `G` and read out all of `G`'s files too.  Git can then *compare* `G`'s files to `H`'s files.  Whatever is the same is uninteresting and Git will tell us nothing about these files, but for each file that is *different*, Git will proceed to *compare* the files, as if playing a game of [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), and will then tells us how to *change* the earlier (commit `G`) version of the file to make it match the later (commit `H`) version of the file.

In this way, Git can *show* us commit `H` as a diff, even though it holds only a snapshot and some metadata.  Git uses the metadata to find the earlier commit `G`.

Of course, having found commit `G`, Git can now use `G`'s metadata to find another commit that is one step earlier than `G`.  That's commit `F`.  Commit `F` also has both snapshot and metadata.  This allows Git to show us commit `G` *as* a diff, even though it *is* a snapshot, and then move one step back to commit `F`.

This repeats until Git has gone through every commit, one at a time, backwards, from "child commit" to "parent commit".  Git gets to *stop* doing this when it reaches a commit that lists *no* parent commit, i.e., a (or the) *root* commit in the repository.

#### Branch names

There's one small flaw in the process outlined above.  To *find* a commit, Git needs its hash ID.  This means we must somehow *remember* the hash ID of the *last* commit `H`.  We don't need to remember the hash ID of earlier commits `G`, `F`, and so on, because we can have Git start with `H` and work backwards; but we *do* need to remember the hash ID of that last commit `H`.  This is where *branch names* come in.

What a branch name does, in Git, is hold the hash ID of the *last* commit in some chain.  The name is up to you (within some limits; see the `git check-ref-format` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format) for details).  The actual hash ID of some commit is determined by the act of making that commit.<sup>3</sup>  So until Git makes the commit, you won't know its hash ID; you know only that it will be unique.

Let's draw in a hash name:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

for instance.  Now the name `main` holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  You just have to remember the name `main` now.

Let's make a second branch name that also points to commit `H`, just like `main`.  We'll call this `feature`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature, main
```

We need some way to know which *name* we're actually using.  Let's attach a special name, `HEAD` (written in all uppercase like this), to one of our branch names:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD), main
```

**Now let's make a new commit.**  Normally I would call this commit `I`—the next letter after `H`—but I'm going to reserve a few letters for a moment and call the *new* commit `K`.  Without worrying yet about *how* we make a new commit, let's just assume that we've had Git do it.  Commit `K`'s *parent* will be commit `H`, so that `K` points back to `H`.  To implement the *last* step of making a new commit, Git will write this new hash ID into the *current branch name*, as indicated by the name `HEAD`.  The result looks like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             K   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

If we make another new commit, we just pick another letter and add on to the chain:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             K--L   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

The name `feature` now selects commit `L`, which leads back to commit `K`, which leads back to commit `H`.

If we now `git checkout main` to get back to `main`, what we'll see in this kind of diagram is that `HEAD` moves:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
            \
             K--L   <-- feature
```

This means we are *using* commit `H`, because `main` is the current *name* and the commit `main` points to is `H`.  If we now make two new commits `I` and `J`, this time it is the name `main` that will advance to cover the new commits:

```
             I--J   <-- main (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- feature
```

This is how we form branches, in Git.  Note that commits up through and including `H` are on *both branches*.

---

<sup>3</sup>Part of the metadata is a date-and-time-stamp.  So, even if you know exactly what *snapshot* you will put in a commit, and what other metadata you will put in a commit, you can't compute the hash ID you'll get until you actually *make* the commit, as Git will add the *current time* to this.  So there's little point in trying to predict what the hash ID will be.  There are some tricks one can use here to force a particular time-stamp, but remember that part of the commit's data includes the parent commit hash.  This means that making a cycle is at least *mostly* as hard as breaking the hash function.

---

#### The mechanics of commits: Git's index and your working tree

We mentioned above that the snapshot *in* a commit is read-only.  It's not *just* read-only: it stores its saved files in a compressed and de-duplicated format that only Git itself can read.  They're not saved *as* files, but rather as internal *objects*.  This means *other* programs cannot use these files at all.

Hence, to get any actual work done, we must have Git *extract* a commit.  We do this with `git checkout` (or, since Git 2.23, `git switch`).  Typically we give `git checkout` a *branch name* like `main` of `feature` or whatever.  This branch name selects some particular commit: the *last* commit that we want Git to say is "in" or "on" the branch.  Git calls this the *tip* commit of the branch.

That tip commit has some frozen snapshot in it.  Git will *expand* the files in this snapshot, turning them back into ordinary everyday files that you can use.  These ordinary files are in what the Git documentation calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.

**The files in your working tree are *yours*.**  They are ordinary everyday files.  They live in an ordinary everyday directory (or folder if you prefer that term).  You can do *anything you want* to and with these files, as they are not *Git's* files.  Git simply copied them out for you, when you asked it to (`git checkout` / `git switch`; note that other commands such as `git restore` and `git reset` can also tell Git to overwrite *your* file with some file copied out of Git).

Because this area *is* yours, you can do anything you like with it, including add all-new-files (that Git doesn't know about), remove existing files, rename files, and so on.  Git is blissfully unaware of all of these activities.<sup>4</sup>  Eventually, though, you must *tell* Git about some of what you have done.  The reason for this is that when you ask Git to make a *new* commit, Git *still* doesn't really look at *your* files.

**This is where Git is very different from many other VCSes.**  In a lot of VCSes, once the VCS knows the *name* of some file, a later commit operation will read the working tree version of that file and use that to make the new commit.  *Git does not do this.*  Instead, Git keeps what amounts to a *third copy* of each file.

When I talk about a third copy, it's reasonable to ask what the other copies are, so let's review that.  Suppose you have files named `README.md` and `LICENSE.md`.  You also have some *current commit*.  That commit presumably has some version of those two files saved in it.  So that's one copy.  The other obvious copy is the one Git had to make in your working tree, so that *you* could read and/or write these files.  That's two active copies of each file: one that you literally can't change, saved in the *current* commit, and one in your work-tree.

The third copy of each of these two files, in Git, sits kind of *between* these two copies.  The frozen committed copy of `README.md` literally can't be changed, but then, in between this frozen `README.md` and your regular everyday file `README.md`, there's one more "copy".  This copy is in in the frozen *format*—pre-de-duplicated and everything—and is *ready to go into a new commit*.  But, not being *in* a commit, Git can remove this copy and replace it with another file.  Technically, Git won't actually *remove* it—it's being shared with the current commit after all—but it will stop using it here and make either an all-new internal object, if your updated `README.md` doesn't match *any* previous version, or it will figure out that your updated `README.md` *does* match some previous version, and start sharing with *that* one.

Hence, this "third copy" is more like a second copy, with your work-tree version being the third copy.  Also, because most files in the *next* commit will probably be the same as most of the files in the *current* commit, this middle copy of each file probably takes almost no space, because it's just sharing with a committed copy.

These extra "copies" (pre-de-duplicated) exist in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or the *cache*.  These three names all refer to the same thing: a place that stores your *proposed next commit*.  Initially, when you `git checkout` some commit, Git fills in this area—its index, or staging area if you prefer that term—*from* the commit.  Git fills in *your* area, your work-tree, from the commit as well.  So *all three copies of every file match*.  The proposed next commit matches the current commit, and matches your work-tree.

As you make changes to your working tree, the files that are in Git's index / staging-area continue to match your *current commit*, so that means they fall out of sync with your working tree copies.  To update your *proposed* next commit, you must run `git add`.

**What `git add` does is make the proposed-commit copy of some file match your work-tree copy.**  If you've updated an existing file, this replaces the index copy (which used to match the committed copy) with the work-tree copy.  If you've created an all-new file, this copies the new file into Git's index, ready to be committed: there was no previous file so this is a new file.  And, if you *remove* a file from your work-tree, what `git add` does is *remove the same file* from Git's index, so that your proposed new commit now *omits* this file.

**When you run `git commit`, the new snapshot Git will make comes from Git's index.**  Any updates you made in your *working tree* don't matter unless you first instruct Git to *copy* those updates into Git's index—your proposed *next* commit.<sup>5</sup>

The `git status` command works by, in part, running *two separate comparisons*.  One compares the current commit's files to the files in the proposed next commit. For all files that match, Git says nothing.  For files that don't match, Git calls these files *staged for commit*.  The second comparison compares the files in the index—the proposed next commit—to those in your work-tree.  Where these match, Git says nothing, but where they don't, Git calls these files *not staged for commit*.

---

<sup>4</sup>Modern Git includes optional *file monitoring* software to make things described here go faster, but this kind of monitoring does not—or at least, is not *supposed to*—make any visible difference other than making things faster.

<sup>5</sup>Even operations like `git commit -a`, `git commit --include`, and `git commit --only` work with *an* index.  The details get complicated because they create one or more *temporary* index files to get this all done, and some of this shows through.  For instance, if you have commit hooks, the fact that `git commit --only` makes *three* index files, and only one of those three has the actual proposed next commit in it—the other two have the rollback version and the proposed-commit-after-next-commit in them, to be used on commit failure or success respectively—makes this tricky.

---

#### Untracked files

Once you understand all of the above—how Git uses its index to hold the proposed next commit, and how Git can produce the `git status` results by comparing against the current commit and against your working tree—you're finally ready to deal with *untracked files*.

Your working tree *is* yours, and you can create files in it that Git knows nothing about.  A diff comparing your proposed next commit in Git's index to your current work-tree may find "newly added" files in the working tree.  It would make sense to report these as added files that are simply unstaged.  But Git doesn't do that.  Instead, Git reports these as *untracked* files.

That, in fact, is all that an untracked file is: it's a file that *is* in your working tree, but *is not* in Git's index *right now*.  Note that you control which files are in your working tree, by creating or deleting them.  Note further that you *can* control which files are in Git's index: you can use `git add` to put one in, when it wasn't there before, and you can use `git rm` to take one out of Git's index when it is there now.

But `git checkout` or `git switch` *fills in Git's index from the commit you are switching to*, to update your proposed *next* commit.  So when you *change commits*, Git's index contents can change here, and this can add or remove a file to/from Git's index.  Again, **this depends on both the commit you're switching from, and the commit you're switching to.**  (Technically, it also depends on the *current contents* of Git's index.  If this matches the current *commit*, though—which it normally must after a successful `git commit`, for instance—then we get to disregard this technicality.)

Note, too, that you can change *branches* without changing *commits*.  Earlier we had this situation:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD), main
```

If we switch to branch `main`, we continue using commit `H`.  Nothing else *has* to change, so nothing else *does* change: Git will leave both its index and your working tree alone.  If we add a *new* branch name and switch to it, again nothing else has to change, and nothing else does change, so:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

results in:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature, main, newbranch (HEAD)
```

It's the act of changing the *current commit* that forces Git to update Git's index.  Of course it's the act of changing the *current branch name* that *usually* results in changing the *current commit*, too, but in these particular special cases, we can change names without changing commits.  (For much–perhaps too much—more on this particular phenomenon, see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452)<>.)

#### Ignored files

This answer would be incomplete without mentioning what Git calls `.gitignore` and "ignored" files.  *Ignore* is the wrong verb here, because these files aren't really *ignored* after all.  Instead, what happens with these files is that *if* they are currently untracked, `git status` will *shut up* about them.

Suppose we have software that, when built by whatever build process we use, produces many build artifacts (`.o` files, dependency files, PDFs, whatever).  Suppose further that we choose not to include these build artifacts in commits (this is usually best practice, though best practice is off topic on StackOverflow).  In this case, running `git status` after running a build *would* produce many pages of complaints about various untracked files.  These are our build artifacts and we *know* they're untracked and just want Git to *stop complaining* about them.

To make Git shut up, we list these file names and/or patterns in one or more files named `.gitignore` or similar.  When we run `git status`, it will do its usual comparisons—finding staged files (differences between current commit and proposed next commit) and unstaged files (differences between proposed next commit and working tree)—and this includes finding all untracked files.  But then it will *filter away* all the *expected* untracked files, and not complain about them.

To make this even more useful, `git add .` or `git add *` will deliberately *not* copy these untracked files into Git's index.  That way, they *stay* untracked.  If `git add` *did* copy them into Git's index, they would become tracked, and the listing in `.gitignore` would be irrelevant.

So, the files named `.gitignore` might be more accurately named `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-files-if-they-are-untracked-and-do-not-add-them-with-en-masse-style-add-commands-either-as-long-as-they-are-untracked-because-they-should-stay-untracked-in-this-case`, or something like that.  But you probably don't want to have to type in this kind of file name: `.gitignore`, as inaccurate as it might be in detail, is a whole lot easier to type in.

#### Scenario

Suppose we have a repository where the last commit on branch `main` has three files in it: `README.md`, `LICENSE.md`, and `main.py`.  We clone this repository (so that we have it locally and can use it) and check out this same last-commit-on-their-`main` as our own last-commit-on-our-own-`main`.

If we now do:

```
echo new > new.txt
```

this creates a whole new file in our working tree.  This file does not exist in the current commit, nor in Git's index.  It is therefore *untracked*.

Now we run:

```
git checkout -b branch
```

which creates a new branch, pointing to the same commit we're already on.  Nothing needs to change in Git's index or our work-tree, so nothing does change.  We still have one untracked file.

We now run:

```
git add new.txt
```

This copies the new file *into* Git's index.  We now have `new.txt` as a *tracked file*.  Its status is "staged for commit" because it does not exist in the *current* commit.  Then we run:

```
git commit -m 'add new.txt'
```

(which is a terrible commit message, but at least it's short).  This creates one new commit, which becomes the tip commit of branch `branch`; this new commit contains *four* files: the original three, exactly matching the previous commit, plus this fourth file.

If we then run:

```
git checkout main
```

to switch back to the earlier commit, Git will:

- notice that we have a file `new.txt` that is in Git's index and our current commit;
- notice that the commit we're switching *to* **lacks** this file; and thus
- remove, from Git's index *and* our working tree, the file `new.txt`.

Examining the working tree files—which, remember, are not *in* Git, they were just *copied out of* Git at some point—we find our familiar three files named `README.md`, `LICENSE.md`, and `main.py`.  These files in our working tree were all created by our initial `git checkout` and have not been touched at all since then (nothing required changing them).

Running `git checkout branch` will create `new.txt` again, because it's in the commit that is the tip of branch `branch`.  That file will also be loaded into Git's index.